# Ranking rows with non linear order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I have to rank these rows:

| Type | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Teddy | 50 |
| Dog | Max | 10 |
| Dog | Rocky | 70 |
| Cat | Zoe | 45 |
| Dog | Buddy | 20 |
| Dog | Daisy | 30 |
| Dog | Duke | 20 |

In this particular way:

| Type | Name | Score | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Rocky | 70 | 1 |
| Dog | Teddy | 50 | 2 |
| Cat | Zoe | 45 | 3 |
| Dog | Daisy | 30 | 3 |
| Dog | Buddy | 20 | 4 |
| Dog | Duke | 20 | 4 |
| Dog | Max | 10 | 6 |

Without the 'Cat' type, it's a normal `RANK()` SQL Function.

The 'Cat' in the ranking should not stole a position of any other dogs. 'Cat' type must have the same rank of the next 'Dog' type regardless of the score.

The `RANK()` functionality is required for all 'dog' type (in the example Buddy and Duke are 4th and Max 6th)

A possibility is create a temporary table/stored procedure and post-elaborate results... but I would like to know if there is an easier way to to this.

Comment: Be great to see what you tried.

Comment: You won't need a temp table for sure. If you provide DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: @DaleK You're in right but I used only a RANK() function... I'm running out of ideas XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the Cat score to be the following Dog score, then rank. (Or dense rank... your desired results don't match either as it stands).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Type,
        Name,
        Score,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Dog' THEN Score END) OVER (ORDER BY Score ASC) NewScore
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT Type, Name, Score,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NewScore DESC) DenseRank,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NewScore DESC) Rank
FROM cte
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

Returns:

| Type | Name | Score | DenseRank | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Rocky | 70 | 1 | 1 |
| Dog | Teddy | 50 | 2 | 2 |
| Cat | Ted | 46 | 3 | 3 |
| Dog | Daisy | 30 | 3 | 3 |
| Dog | Buddy | 20 | 4 | 6 |
| Dog | Duke | 20 | 4 | 6 |
| Dog | Max | 10 | 5 | 8 |

Oh I may have misunderstood... from your desired results, maybe you want to rank the Dogs first, then the Cats just join in... in that case this is what you need

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Type,
        Name,
        Score,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'Dog' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Type = 'Dog' THEN 1 END ORDER BY Score DESC) END DogRank
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT Type, Name, Score,
    MIN(DogRank) OVER (ORDER BY Score ASC) Rank
FROM cte
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

Returns:

| Type | Name | Score | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Rocky | 70 | 1 |
| Dog | Teddy | 50 | 2 |
| Cat | Ted | 46 | 3 |
| Dog | Daisy | 30 | 3 |
| Dog | Duke | 20 | 4 |
| Dog | Buddy | 20 | 4 |
| Dog | Max | 10 | 6 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NjOPsdA3)

Comment: That's clever using MAX to bunch them together!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is a combination of:

- `RANK()` with the appropriate partition (to rank only the rows where the `Type` is `Dog`) and the correct `ORDER BY` clause.
- `LEAD()` with `IGNORE NULLS` (introduced in SQL Server 2022).

Note, that if you want to get a rank with no gaps in the ranking values, you may use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `RANK()`.

Sample test data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES  
   ('Dog', 'Teddy', 50),
   ('Cat', 'Mary', 1),
   ('Cat', 'Ana', 70),
   ('Dog', 'Max', 10),
   ('Dog', 'Rocky', 70),
   ('Cat', 'Zoe', 45),
   ('Cat', 'Nelly', 40),
   ('Dog', 'Buddy', 20),
   ('Dog', 'Daisy', 30),
   ('Dog', 'Duke', 20)
) v (Type, Name, Score)
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT
   Type, Name, Score, DogRank,
   Rank = COALESCE(
      DogRank, 
      LEAD(DogRank) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC, DogRank),
      COUNT(*) OVER ()
      -- or MAX(DogRank) OVER () + 1 
   )
FROM (  
   SELECT 
      *,
      DogRank = CASE WHEN Type = 'Dog' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Type = 'Dog' THEN 1 END ORDER BY Score DESC) END
   FROM Data
) t  
ORDER BY Score DESC, DogRank
```

Result:

| Type | Name | Score | DogRank | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Ana | 70 | *null* | 1 |
| Dog | Rocky | 70 | 1 | 1 |
| Dog | Teddy | 50 | 2 | 2 |
| Cat | Zoe | 45 | *null* | 3 |
| Cat | Nelly | 40 | *null* | 3 |
| Dog | Daisy | 30 | 3 | 3 |
| Dog | Duke | 20 | 4 | 4 |
| Dog | Buddy | 20 | 4 | 4 |
| Dog | Max | 10 | 6 | 6 |
| Cat | Mary | 1 | *null* | 10 |

Comment: There are 2 issues with this...
1) If Zoe has 70 (like Rocky), its Rank is 2 but its should be 1
2) if Zoe has 1, its Rank is 'null' instead 8

Comment: @Samuel you need to add all edge cases to your sample data. And you explain how if Zoe was 1 the rank would be 8? And in fact how Zoe 70 should be rank 1 instead of 2 as you said a cat should never outrank a dog

Comment: @Samuel, a solution for the first edge case (... If Zoe has 70 as score ...) is a different `ORDER BY` clause in the `LEAD()` function, but I'm not sure why do you want rank 8 (instead of 7) if Zoe has 1 as score. The answer is updated using additional test data.